# Meaning of -> shorthand in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I was browsing [Friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) code base and I found [line](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id.rb#L117) with following assignment:

```
@defaults ||= ->(config) {config.use :reserved}
```

My questions are:

1. How do I interpret this line of code?
2. What does exactly `->` do and what does it mean?
3. Is there any articles about it, how to use it?(Official Ruby documentation would be nice, I haven't found it)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Here's a tip, when you search using Stack Overflow's built-in Elastic Search, you can search for code by putting them in quotation marks, [like this: `"->" ruby`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22-%3E%22+ruby).

Comment: So this was the reason why I wasn't able to find it. I tried, but didn't know about this functionality of search. Thanks for letting me know. I will use it next time.

Comment: Please see also [What is the proper way to approach SO as someone totally new to programming?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254579/456814) for more search tips.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This denotes the [**`lambda`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F). With this you are latching an anonymous function which takes a parameter *config* and computes a block using that variable.

The above expression can also be defined as:

```
@defaults ||= lambda {|config| config.use :reserved}
```

[`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html) is similar to `lambda` in Ruby, apart from few differences of return and break pattern. *Proc* can be called as a block saved as an object, while *lambda* is a *method* saved as an object. They find their roots in **functional programming**.

In short, a lambda is a named procedure, which can be saved as an *object* and can be called later.

```
inc = ->x{ x + 1 }
inc.call(3)
#=> 4
```

One common and interesting example of `lambda` is [**Rails Scope**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope), where a method is simply assigned in name scope as lambda and can be later used as an action while ActiveRecord querying.

Comment: Now its clear. This shorthand was introduced already in Ruby 1.9. Well, thank you, for great answer. I learn new stuff every single day:)

Comment: The other thing interesting about the new format is you can specify a default value for the argument.  Old format "inc = lambda {|x|x+1}" compare to "inc = ->(x=0){x+1}" so now the argument is optional and "inc.call" without argument specified is #=> 1